# Istanbul test coverage information

Tags: node.js, test-coverage, nyc

I am using this tool(https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc) for checking test coverage of my code, and I get output smth like this:
[image]

So, question is how can I get information just in numbers, without parsing this table? maybe nyc has api for retrieving such information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is answered [here](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/970).